# Can not run standalone Google App Script from a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet shared with co-workers to keep track of task status. And I want to set a function through a menu to block some ranges in which the tasks were completed. The protective permissions are set to only allow me (owner) to edit it.

I've built a standalone script to `run as me` for this shared spreadsheet by using `UrlFetch`. I've tried many kinds of codes but it didn't work. The below are 3 versions I tried.

And, of course, I set "Who has access to the app: Anyone, even anonymous" in the standalone script.
[Photo 1: Standalone script setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXW7I.jpg)

Thanks so much!

**1st version: Without using Content Service**

```
//In standalone script
function doGet(e){
   var taskRange = e.parameter.taskRange;
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHARING_SPREADSHEET_ID');
   var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
   var protection = sh.getRange(taskRange).protect().setDescription('Completed Task')
   var result = protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors())
   return result
   }

//In sharing spreadsheet script
var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/STANDALONE_SCRIPT_ID/exec"
function onOpen(){
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('TASK')
  .addItem('Protect Task', 'protectTask')
  .addToUi();
}
function protectTask(){
var taskRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange()
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+"?taskRange="+taskRange);
Logger.log(response);
}
```

**2nd version: Using Content Service**

```
//In standalone script
function doGet(e){
   var taskRange = e.parameter.taskRange;
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHARING_SPREADSHEET_ID');
   var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
   var protection = sh.getRange(taskRange).protect().setDescription('Completed Task')
   var result = protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors())
   return ContentService.createTextOutput(result)
   }

//In sharing spreadsheet script
var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/STANDALONE_SCRIPT_ID/exec"
function onOpen(){
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('TASK')
  .addItem('Protect Task', 'protectTask')
  .addToUi();
}
function protectTask(){
var taskRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange()
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+"?taskRange="+taskRange).getContentText();
Logger.log(response);
}
```

**3rd version: Using Content Service with JSON**

```
//In standalone script
function doGet(e){
   var taskRange = e.parameter.taskRange;
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHARING_SPREADSHEET_ID');
   var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
   var protection = sh.getRange(taskRange).protect().setDescription('Completed Task')
   var result = protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors())
   return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
   }

//In sharing spreadsheet script
var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/STANDALONE_SCRIPT_ID/exec"
function onOpen(){
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('TASK')
  .addItem('Protect Task', 'protectTask')
  .addToUi();
}
function protectTask(){
var taskRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange()
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+"?taskRange="+taskRange).getContentText();
var result = JSON.Parse(response)
Logger.log(result);
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  Does the range get protected?  Does a response fail to get returned?  Is a response returned, but not what you want?  In the stand alone script, log the stringified `result`.  `var resultStr = JSON.stringify(result);  Logger.log('resultStr: ' + resultStr);`

Comment: Hi Sandy Good. Thanks for the comment.
The range doesn't get protected as well as nothing returned. The version 3 got error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token: e".
I tried your suggestion but still not working.

Comment: It will likely have something to do with how you actually call the script. `doGet(e)` would indicate that it's called by some sort of trigger, however since it's standalone, you can't use any trigger that is associated with the spreadsheet itself.

Comment: @Vytautas you are right. "A [standalone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone#using_a_standalone_script) can also be deployed as a web app or set up to run automatically from an installable trigger". Unfortunately, I cannot find any triggers that can call the script from Google Spreadsheet. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: Every time that you change the code, no matter how small a change, you must re-publish the Web App, or the `doGet(e)` function that runs will be outdated code.  The "exec" version is not like the "dev" version.  The "dev" version always runs the latest change.  The "exec" version only runs the last published code.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is this line:

```
var taskRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange()
```

Should be:

```
var taskRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
```

Currently, the variable `taskRange` is a "class"  It's not a string.  You need to send a string.

Comment: Thanks to correct me. Actually I've tried a specific range (e.g. 'A5:E5') but nothing to come. Could you show me how to send a string?

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY IT WORKS. I think the script was not running properly because I modified many times with many kinds of code. Therefore, I've created a new one and used the "stringified" log as @SandyGood suggested.
Many thanks to you all, specially, @SandyGood.

**FINAL SCRIPTS**

```
//In standalone script
function doGet(e){
var taskRange = e.parameter.taskRange;
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHARING_SPREADSHEET_ID');
var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var protection = sh.getRange(taskRange).protect().setDescription('Completed Task');
var result = protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
var resultStr = JSON.stringify(result);
Logger.log('resultStr: ' + resultStr);
}

//In sharing spreadsheet script
var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/STANDALONE_SCRIPT_ID/exec"
function onOpen(){
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('TASK')
   .addItem('Protect Task', 'protectTask')
   .addToUi();
}
function protectTask(){
var taskRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+"?taskRange="+taskRange).getContentText();
Logger.log(response);
}
```